# How can I fix my ASP.NET Razor markup?

Tags: asp.net, razor

**Example markup:**

```
<a target = "_blank" href="/PDFFiles/@(item.PdfFileName).pdf#page=@item.PdfPageNo)">XXX</a>
```

How can I remove the final parenthesis after `.PdfPageNo`?

Answer (score 2):

You should put open paranthesis before @item.PdfPageNo. Final would look like

```
<a target = "_blank" href="/PDFFiles/@(item.PdfFileName).pdf#page=@(item.PdfPageNo)">XXX</a>
```

Comment: Your suggestion does not really answer the question. I already tried that. I accept that it SHOULD work but doing as you suggest causes squiggly lines under the words /PDFFiles, pdf and page. It is a pity I cannot work out how to upload an image to show what I mean. I suppose it is out of the question for you to actually enter the line yourself? Many thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, can you just paste your generated anchor html here?

Comment: Your idea works so generated code will not help.
It is the squiggly lines I get when I include the extra parenthesis that I am concerned about.
Error for /Content/PDFFiles:
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): If this attribute is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.
Error for pdf:
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): This attribute name must be floowed by an equal (=) sign and a value. If the value is in quotation markks, the quotation marks must match.
Error for pdf:page:
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attirbute 'page' is not a valid attribute of element 'a'